# What is the smallest size of text that is allowed for an Adsense advertisement label?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, text

What is the smallest size of text that is allowed for an Adsense advertisement label?

I ask this because on my mobile pages, I don't really have much screen space to work with for above-the-fold since the photo nearly takes up the whole screen on smaller devices, and I want some of the advertisement to appear above-the-fold if at all possible and I also want users to still see the pictures without scrolling.

I also don't want to omit the label because if I do, then someone might believe an ad would be internal to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about font size? 6px or larger is advised. Maybe one of these links can help you out.

- http://adsense.blogspot.com/2009/06/font-size-matters.html
- https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6002621?hl=en

If you choose a decent font-family, it'll always be easy to read as your viewport is scaled. Consider working with (r)ems to avoid gigantic mismatched fonts on smaller devices.